# C# list.remove(item) removes item from other list I want

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code:

```
List<T> firstList; //list with some items
List<T> secondList = firstList //copyOfFirstList


List<T> elementsToDelete = secondList.FindAll(whichShouldIDelete);


foreach(var item in elementsToDelete){
     secondList.Remove(item);
}
```

The problem is that Remove() method does not delete items only from secondList. Items are deleted from both firstList and secondList. So when I remove 20 items from secondList, the same elements are removed from firstList. What may be the cause of this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
List<T> secondList = firstList //copyOfFirstList
```

It is not creating a copy of the list, instead there are now **two references pointing to the same instance** of list.

You can do:

```
List<T> secondList = firstList.ToList(); // explicitly creating a new list.
```

or

```
List<T> secondList = new List<T>(firstList);
```

But remember, if your `List<T>` has a reference type *(class)* then the object of each list would point to the same instance. (A shallow copy of object will be available). So if you do:

```
firstList[0].SomeProperty = 2;
```

and if that item exists in `secondList` then you will see the property change in second list as well.

Comment: You beat me 19 seconds. At least I beat Mr. Korneyev ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption:

```
List<T> secondList = firstList //copyOfFirstList
```

is only partially right. Is it a shallow reference copy.

The secondList refers to the same object in a different variable.

Google for DeepCopy List to find answers that may match your expectation

Comment: "Is it a shallow reference copy" I _think_ you mean that the reference in `secondList` is "copied" to `firstList`, which is correct.  However, I first read it as a _true_ ["shallow copy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy), which mean that the value of each field of the object is copied, which is _not_ true.  I would consider `.ToList()` a "shallow copy" since it copies all of the _references_ in the list, but does not copy the objects that the references point to.  In fact, a shallow copy _would_ solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

As `List<T>` is reference type, not value one, then `List<T> secondList = firstList;` is not a copy, but just a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

It is because both lists point to the same "address", so editing one affects the other.

try

```
List<T> firstList = new List<T>();
List<T> secondList = new List<T>();
secondList.AddRange(firstList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<T> CloneList<T>(List<T> oldList)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, oldList);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (List<T>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> firstList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3"}; //list with some items
        List<string> secondList = CloneList(firstList); //copyOfFirstList

        List<string> elementsToDelete = new List<string>() { "1" }; // do some logic to find all items you need to delete

        foreach (var item in elementsToDelete)
        {
            secondList.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```